# Endpoints API with authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

My question is : can I use endpoints API or a service with OAuth protocol in general, in sort of that i not need to authenticate the user all time that it send a request to the server but only the first time and for the other times I will use type of token or whatever to use the server directly without check oaut. ALl that in a secure way of course. 
the process of check oaut is slowing the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "authenticate the user". OAuth as implemented by Endpoints (and demonstrated with samples) suggests you authenticate the user the first time they use the application (either at install time, or each time they load the app in the browser). From then on, the identity of the user is represented by a token, managed by the client library, and sent along with each request. The server will *always* verify this token to determine who is making the request, but it does not require user-facing interaction.

If you're asking whether you can use OAuth without continually making the user identify themselves (via an OAuth popup, etc.), yes, this is the way it works by default in the samples.

If you're asking whether you can use OAuth without verifying the tokens on each request, you *could*, but it's not worth doing, because it doesn't get you a lot from a security perspective or save you much performance-wise.

Comment: Really Thanks. Please can you show me sample link that you say about and some link about token. how an android app need to use the token and how it get it ? Thank you

Comment: There are a few examples. This project contains a Java backend and JS frontend with proper use of tokens: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java. This project contains an Android app designed to work with the Java backend: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android